# KendoDropDownList - cascading data from one drop down to another

Tags: kendo-ui

I am making a game, and have a specific requirement where players pick a playable character race, and then I want a second drop down list to show the list of available genders for that race. I thought this would be easy to do using the `Cascade` property of the `kendo.ui.DropDownListOptions`... like this.

```
var racesOptions = {
        index: -1,
        valuePrimitive: true,
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Name",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/api/races/list',
                    type: 'GET'
                }
            }
        }
};

var genderOptions = {
    index: -1,
    valuePrimitive: true,
    cascadeFrom: 'race',
    cascadeFromField: 'Genders'
};
```

The shape of data coming in from `/api/races/list` looks like this;

```
[{
    "Name": "race1",
    // ... other data ... //
    "Genders": [ "Male", "Female", "Other" ]
}, {
    "Name": "race2",
    // ... other data ... //
    "Genders" : ["Female"]
}, {
    "Name": "race3",
    // ... other data ... //
    "Genders": ["Male"]
}]
```

I thought this was going to be a no-brainer. The second drop down cascades from the first; When the first has a value, I figured the second would get the `CascadeFromField`value. But that's not happening... In fact, the only way I've been able to accomplish this is with the following code in the `#race` widget's `change` event.

```
change: function (e) {
    // the specific race entity selected
    var entity = e.sender.dataItem().toJSON();
    // set the selected race's genders
    var genders = $('#genders').data('kendoDropDownList');
    genders.destroy();
    genders = $('#genders').kendoDropDownList({
        index: -1,
        valuePrimitive: true,
        dataSource: {
            data: entity.Genders
        }
    }).data('kendoDropDownList');
    genders.select(-1);
    genders.trigger('change');
}
```

That change event does work, but it's messy and kind of obtuse. Is there another way I can get the Cascading to work as I'm expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `cascadeFromField:` needs to point to the parent ID field. In your case the ID field in the Races datasource.

Here's a small example that should help.

```
<h4>Race:</h4>
<input id="race" />

<h4>Gender:</h4>
<input id="gender" />

<script>
    $("#race").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select race...",
        dataTextField: "raceName",
        dataValueField: "raceID",
        dataSource: [
            { raceName: "Race1", raceID: 1 },
            { raceName: "Race2", raceID: 2 },
            { raceName: "Race3", raceID: 3 }
        ]
    });

    $("#gender").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select gender...",
        cascadeFrom: "race",
        cascadeFromField: "raceID",
        dataTextField: "genderName",
        dataValueField: "genderID",
        dataSource: [
            { genderName: "Male", genderID: 1, raceID: 1 },
            { genderName: "Female", genderID: 2, raceID: 1 },
            { genderName: "Other", genderID: 3, raceID: 1 },
            { genderName: "Female", genderID: 4, raceID: 2 },
            { genderName: "Male", genderID: 4, raceID: 3 }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

You can check out this [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aMeja) using the above code.

Comment: So it isn't possible to do with `valuePrimitive`? The gender isn't a full fledged object, it's just a `string`.